# Publishing app screenshots to the Apple App store

Tags: ios, iphone, store

When publishing my app to the Apple app store, can I add screenshot designs for the iPhone 6.5-inch size and iPhone 5.5-inch size designed using the same iPhone 11 mockup? But the screenshot design images are in the separate proper size.
(6.5 inch size - 1242 x 2688)
(5.5 inch size - 1242 x 2208)

Is that ok with app store guidelines or any other rules?

Answer (score 3):

According to Apple's policy for showing the content responsive to the device , you should add different screenshot for different dimensions, [here](https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/devd274dd925) you can find the dimensions , there are also other things you need to keep in mind:

- The Screen shots should not include any lorem ipsum texts
- They should not violate any person's policy (sharing someone's picture with info etc.)
- It should not include word free

there are also other rules but these are main ones.

for more info you can also go through :

https://developer.apple.com/app-store/marketing/guidelines/

https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/

Answer (score 1):

"App Store screenshots should accurately communicate your app’s value and functionality. Use text and overlay images to highlight your app’s user experience, not obscure it. Make sure app UI and product images match the corresponding device type in App Store Connect. This helps users understand your app and makes for a positive App Store experience."

Link: https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/

You can make a judgment call based on this.

Answer (score 1):

If you have only one iPhone to make screenshots, you can use the simulator to make the screenshots for any supported device. It will be in resolution of the device.
Use screenshot command from simulator menus.

Comment: Thanks for your help. But I am not uploading just screenshots. I am uploading screenshot designs created by adding screenshots into iPhone mockups. Resolution of final screenshot design images will be different for the different sizes (6.5, 5.5 sizes). I want to know if using the same iPhone 11 mockup for the screenshot designs of both 6.5 and 5.5 sizes is ok with app store guidelines.

Comment: The 2 screen have also different height/width ratio that may change a little what is displayed on screen : more height or more width..